# Stripe unable to find routing number formats json country wise

Tags: stripe-payments

i am working on stripe and i did not find any api which **Bank account formats by country** like  https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payouts#formats, do i need to create it manually!! it's wired check below what kind of data i am talking 
json data example

```
{  
   "United Kingdom (GB)":{  
      "required fields":[  
         "Sort Code",
         "Account Number"
      ]
   },
   "United States (US)":{  
      "required fields":[  
         "Routing Number",
         "Account Number"
      ]
   },
   "Japan (JP)":{  
      "required fields":[  
         "Bank Name",
         "Account Number",
         "Branch Name",
         "Bank Code",
         "Branch Code",
         "Account Number",
         "Account Owner Name"
      ]
   }
}
```

above example is for three countries i want this for all countries so do i need to make it by my self. don't i can have this from stripe please help me thanks in advance i am not working with **stripe connect** express and standard accounts i am working with **stripe connect** custom accounts

Comment: Yes, you're correct, at this time it does not appear that there is an API for format of bank account by country, so it is something you'd need to handle / consider manually.

Comment: yes but this is not good as stripe is big platform can we report this to any stripe platform

Comment: I'd email stripe if you want to give them feedback on this https://support.stripe.com/contact

Comment: @duck please check my answer to my own question

Answer (score 1):

```
{  
   "Australia (AU)":{  
      "required fields":[  
         "BSB",
         "Account Number"
      ]
   },
   "Austria (AT)":{  
      "required fields":[  
         "IBAN"
      ]
   },
   "Belgium (BE)":{  
      "required fields":[  
          "IBAN"
      ]`enter code here`
   },
   "Brazil (BR)":{  
      "required fields":[  
          "Bank Code",
          "Branch Code",
          "Account Number"
      ]
   },
   "Bulgaria (BG)":{  
      "required fields":[  
          "IBAN"
      ]
   },
   "Canada (CA)":{  
      "required fields":[  
          "Transit number",
          "Institution number",
          "Account number"
      ]
   },
   "Cyprus (CY)":{  
      "required fields":[  
          "IBAN"
      ]
   },
   "Czech Republic (CZ)":{  
      "required fields":[  
          "IBAN"
      ]
   },
   "Denmark (DK)":{  
      "required fields":[  
          "IBAN"
      ]
   },
   "Estonia (EE)":{  
      "required fields":[  
          "IBAN"
      ]
   },
   "Finland (FI)":{  
      "required fields":[  
          "IBAN"
      ]
   },
   "France (FR)":{  
      "required fields":[  
          "IBAN"
      ]
   },
   "Germany (DE)":{  
      "required fields":[  
          "IBAN"
      ]
   },
   "Gibraltar (GI)":{  
      "required fields":[  
          "IBAN"
      ]
   },
   "Greece (GR)":{  
      "required fields":[  
          "IBAN"
      ]
   },
   "Hong Kong (HK)":{  
      "required fields":[  
          "Clearing Code",
          "Branch code",
          "Account number"
      ]
   },
   "Hungary (HU)":{  
      "required fields":[  
          "IBAN"
      ]
   },
   "India (IN)":{  
      "required fields":[  
          "IFSC Code",
          "Account number"
      ]
   },
   "Ireland (IE)":{  
      "required fields":[  
          "IBAN"
      ]
   },
   "Italy (IT)":{  
      "required fields":[  
          "IBAN"
      ]
   },
   "Japan (JP)":{  
      "required fields":[  
          "Bank name",
          "Branch name",
          "Bank code",
          "Branch code",
          "Account number",
          "Account owner name"
      ]
   },
   "Liechtenstein (LI)":{  
      "required fields":[  
          "IBAN"
      ]
   },
   "Lithuania (LT)":{  
      "required fields":[  
          "IBAN"
      ]
   },
   "Luxembourg (LU)":{  
      "required fields":[  
          "IBAN"
      ]
   },
   "Latvia (LV)":{  
      "required fields":[  
          "IBAN"
      ]
   },
   "Malta (MT)":{  
      "required fields":[  
          "IBAN"
      ]
   },
   "Malaysia (MY)":{  
      "required fields":[  
          "Account number"
      ]
   },
   "Mexico (MX)":{  
      "required fields":[  
          "CLABE"
      ]
   },
   "Netherlands (NL)":{  
      "required fields":[  
          "IBAN"
      ]
   },
   "New Zealand (NZ)":{  
      "required fields":[  
          "Account number"
      ]
   },
   "Norway (NO)":{  
      "required fields":[  
         "IBAN"
      ]
   },
   "Poland (PL)":{  
      "required fields":[  
          "IBAN"
      ]
   },
   "Portugal (PT)":{  
      "required fields":[  
          "IBAN"
      ]
   },
   "Romania (RO)":{  
      "required fields":[  
          "IBAN"
      ]
   },
   "Singapore (SG)":{  
      "required fields":[  
          "Bank code",
          "Branch code",
          "Account number"
      ]
   },
   "Slovakia (SK)":{  
      "required fields":[  
          "IBAN"
      ]
   },
   "Slovenia (SI)":{  
      "required fields":[  
          "IBAN"
      ]
   },
   "Spain (ES)":{  
      "required fields":[  
          "IBAN"
      ]
   },
   "Sweden (SE)":{  
      "required fields":[  
          "IBAN"
      ]
   },
   "Switzerland (CH)":{  
      "required fields":[  
          "IBAN"
      ]
   },
   "United Kingdom (GB)":{  
      "required fields":[  
          "Sort Code",
          "Account number"
      ]
   },
   "United States (US)":{  
      "required fields":[  
          "Routing Number",
          "Account number"
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While your answer may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. You can edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/28435205)

Answer (score 0):

is that the answer to my question i am asking this question to all stripe connect and stripe experienced developers which are on stackoverflow

```
 <?php
$country_iban=[
    "AT"=>["field1"=>["placeholder"=>"AT611904300235473201","name"=>"IBAN"]],
    "BE"=>["field1"=>["placeholder"=>"BE12345678912345","name"=>"IBAN"]],
    "DK"=>["field1"=>["placeholder"=>"DK5000400440116243","name"=>"IBAN"]],
    "EE"=>["field1"=>["placeholder"=>"","name"=>"IBAN"]],
    "FI"=>["field1"=>["placeholder"=>"FI2112345600000785","name"=>"IBAN"],],
    "FR"=>["field1"=>["placeholder"=>"FR1420041010050500013M02606","name"=>"IBAN"],],
    "DE"=>["field1"=>["placeholder"=>"DE89370400440532013000","name"=>"IBAN"]],
    "GI"=>["field1"=>["placeholder"=>"","name"=>"IBAN"]],
    "IE"=>["field1"=>["placeholder"=>"IE29AIBK93115212345678","name"=>"IBAN"]],
    "IT"=>["field1"=>["placeholder"=>"IT60X0542811101000000123456","name"=>"IBAN"]],
    "LU"=>["field1"=>["placeholder"=>"LU280019400644750000","name"=>"IBAN"]],
    "NL"=>["field1"=>["placeholder"=>"NL39RABO0300065264","name"=>"IBAN"]],
    "NO"=>["field1"=>["placeholder"=>"NO9386011117947","name"=>"IBAN"]],
    "PT"=>["field1"=>["placeholder"=>"PT50123443211234567890172","name"=>"IBAN"]],
    "ES"=>["field1"=>["placeholder"=>"ES9121000418450200051332","name"=>"IBAN"]],
    "SE"=>["field1"=>["placeholder"=>"SE3550000000054910000003","name"=>"IBAN"]],
    "CH"=>["field1"=>["placeholder"=>"CH9300762011623852957","name"=>"IBAN"]],
    "ES"=>["field1"=>["placeholder"=>"DK5000400440116243","name"=>"IBAN"]],
    "GB"=>["field1"=>["placeholder"=>"GB82WEST12345698765432","name"=>"IBAN"]],
];
$currencies_by_country=[
    "chf"=>["field1"=>["placeholder"=>"CH9300762011623852957","name"=>"IBAN"],"field2"=>["name"=>"Account Number","placeholder"=>""]],
    "dkk"=>["field1"=>["placeholder"=>"DK5000400440116243","name"=>"IBAN"],"field2"=>["name"=>"Account Number","placeholder"=>""]],
    "eur"=>[$country_iban],
    "gbp"=>["field1"=>["placeholder"=>"12-34-56","name"=>"Sort Code"],"field2"=>["name"=>"Account Number","placeholder"=>""]],
    "nok"=>["field1"=>["placeholder"=>"NO9386011117947","name"=>"IBAN"],"field2"=>["name"=>"Account Number","placeholder"=>""]],
    "sek"=>["field1"=>["placeholder"=>"SE3550000000054910000003","name"=>"IBAN"],"field2"=>["name"=>"Account Number","placeholder"=>""]],
    "usd"=>["field1"=>["placeholder"=>"111000000","name"=>"Routing Number"],"field2"=>["name"=>"Account Number","placeholder"=>""]],
];
return [
    "AU"=>[
        "field1"=>["placeholder"=>"123456","name"=>"BSB"],
        "field2"=>["name"=>"Account Number","placeholder"=>""]],
    "AT"=>[$currencies_by_country],
    "BE"=>[$currencies_by_country],
    "CA"=>[],
    "DK"=>[$currencies_by_country],
    "EE"=>[$currencies_by_country],
    "FI"=>[$currencies_by_country],
    "FR"=>[$currencies_by_country],
    "DE"=>[
        "field1"=>["placeholder"=>"123","name"=>"Bank code"],
        "field2"=>["placeholder"=>"456","name"=>"Branch code"],
        "field3"=>["placeholder"=>"123456","name"=>"Account number"]],
    "HK"=>[$currencies_by_country],
    "IE"=>[$currencies_by_country],
    "IT"=>[$currencies_by_country],
    "LU"=>[$currencies_by_country],
    "NL"=>[$currencies_by_country],
    "NO"=>[$currencies_by_country],
    "PT"=>[$currencies_by_country],
    "SG"=>[
        "field1"=>["placeholder"=>"123","name"=>"Bank code"],
        "field2"=>["placeholder"=>"456","name"=>"Branch code"],
        "field3"=>["placeholder"=>"123456","name"=>"Account number"]
    ],
    "ES"=>[$currencies_by_country],
    "SE"=>[$currencies_by_country],
    "CH"=>[$currencies_by_country],
    "GB"=>[
        "chf"=>["field1"=>["placeholder"=>"CH9300762011623852957","name"=>"IBAN"],"field2"=>["name"=>"Account Number","placeholder"=>""]],
        "dkk"=>["field1"=>["placeholder"=>"DK5000400440116243","name"=>"IBAN"],"field2"=>["name"=>"Account Number","placeholder"=>""]],
        "eur"=>[$country_iban],
        "gbp"=>["field1"=>["placeholder"=>"12-34-56","name"=>"Sort Code"],"field2"=>["name"=>"Account Number","placeholder"=>""]],
        "nok"=>["field1"=>["placeholder"=>"NO9386011117947","name"=>"IBAN"],"field2"=>["name"=>"Account Number","placeholder"=>""]],
        "sek"=>["field1"=>["placeholder"=>"SE3550000000054910000003","name"=>"IBAN"],"field2"=>["name"=>"Account Number","placeholder"=>""]],
        "usd"=>["field1"=>["placeholder"=>"111000000","name"=>"Routing Number"],"field2"=>["name"=>"Account Number","placeholder"=>""]],
    ],
    "US"=>[
        "field1"=>["placeholder"=>"111000000","name"=>"Routing Number"],"field2"=>["name"=>"Account Number","placeholder"=>""]
    ]
 ]




?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'v inspected the code in the stripe documentation page. With the window.**INITIAL_STATE** field who is exposed, i'v parsed it to get the following values :

```
{
    "AL": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "DZ": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "Account Number"
    ],
    "AO": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "AG": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "Account number"
    ],
    "AR": [
        "CBU"
    ],
    "AM": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "Account number"
    ],
    "AU": [
        "BSB",
        "Account number"
    ],
    "AT": [
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "AZ": [
        "Bank code",
        "Branch code",
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "BS": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "Account Number"
    ],
    "BH": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "BD": [
        "Bank code",
        "Account Number"
    ],
    "BE": [
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "BJ": [
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "BT": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "Account number"
    ],
    "BO": [
        "Bank code",
        "Account number"
    ],
    "BA": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "BW": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "Account Number"
    ],
    "BR": [
        "Bank code",
        "Branch code",
        "Account number"
    ],
    "BN": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "Account number"
    ],
    "BG": [
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "KH": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "Account Number"
    ],
    "CA": [
        "Transit number",
        "Institution number",
        "Account number"
    ],
    "CL": [
        "Bank code",
        "Account number",
        "Bank account type"
    ],
    "CO": [
        "Bank code",
        "Account number",
        "Bank account type"
    ],
    "CR": [
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "CI": [
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "HR": [
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "CY": [
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "CZ": [
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "DK": [
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "DO": [
        "Bank Code",
        "Branch Code",
        "Account number"
    ],
    "EC": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "Account number"
    ],
    "EG": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "SV": [
        "SWIFT / BIC",
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "EE": [
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "ET": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "Account Number"
    ],
    "FI": [
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "FR": [
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "GA": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "Account Number"
    ],
    "GM": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "Account number"
    ],
    "DE": [
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "GH": [
        "Bank sort code",
        "Account number"
    ],
    "GI": [
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "GR": [
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "GT": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "GY": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "Account number"
    ],
    "HK": [
        "Clearing Code",
        "Branch code",
        "Account number"
    ],
    "HU": [
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "IS": [
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "IN": [
        "IFSC Code",
        "Account number"
    ],
    "ID": [
        "Bank name",
        "Bank code",
        "Account number"
    ],
    "IE": [
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "IL": [
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "IT": [
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "JM": [
        "Bank Code",
        "Branch Code",
        "Account number"
    ],
    "JP": [
        "Bank name",
        "Branch name",
        "Bank code",
        "Branch code",
        "Account number",
        "Account owner name"
    ],
    "JO": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "KZ": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "KE": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "Account number"
    ],
    "KW": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "LA": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "Account Number"
    ],
    "LV": [
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "LI": [
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "LT": [
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "LU": [
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "MO": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "Account number"
    ],
    "MG": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "MY": [
        "Bank name",
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "Account number"
    ],
    "MT": [
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "MU": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "MX": [
        "CLABE"
    ],
    "MD": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "Account number"
    ],
    "MC": [
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "MN": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "Account Number"
    ],
    "MA": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "Account Number"
    ],
    "MZ": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "Account Number"
    ],
    "NA": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "Account number"
    ],
    "NL": [
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "NZ": [
        "Account number"
    ],
    "NE": [
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "NG": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "Account number (NUBAN)"
    ],
    "MK": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "Account number"
    ],
    "NO": [
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "OM": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "Account number"
    ],
    "PK": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "PA": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "Account number"
    ],
    "PY": [
        "Bank code",
        "Account number"
    ],
    "PE": [
        "CCI"
    ],
    "PH": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "Account number"
    ],
    "PL": [
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "PT": [
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "QA": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "Account number"
    ],
    "RO": [
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "RW": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "Account Number"
    ],
    "LC": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "Account number"
    ],
    "SA": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "SM": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "SN": [
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "RS": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "Account number"
    ],
    "SG": [
        "Bank code",
        "Branch code",
        "Account number"
    ],
    "SK": [
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "SI": [
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "ZA": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "Account number"
    ],
    "KR": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "Account number"
    ],
    "ES": [
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "LK": [
        "Bank code",
        "Branch code",
        "Account Number"
    ],
    "SE": [
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "CH": [
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "TW": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "Account number"
    ],
    "TZ": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "Account Number"
    ],
    "TH": [
        "Bank name",
        "Bank code",
        "Account number"
    ],
    "TT": [
        "Bank code",
        "Branch code",
        "Account number"
    ],
    "TN": [
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "TR": [
        "SWIFT / BIC Code",
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "GB": [
        "Sort Code",
        "Account number"
    ],
    "US": [
        "Routing Number",
        "Account number"
    ],
    "AE": [
        "IBAN"
    ],
    "UY": [
        "Bank code",
        "Account number"
    ],
    "UZ": [
        "Bank Code",
        "Branch Code",
        "Account Number"
    ],
    "VN": [
        "Bank code",
        "Account number"
    ]
}
```